# How to get Get Azure App Service folders in wwwroot

Tags: azure, azure-appservice

I have a Query to remove folders from Azure App service after specific **number of Releases**.
I deploy using SFTP connection and there is an additional option to **Remove Additional Files at Destination** but this does not helps me. Since I want to remove specific files after deployments. It remove all the files.

I have tried **Azure Rest api** this too didn't help me out.

Need a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

- You can  View, Add, Edit, and Remove files in Azure Web App using `Kudu`
- Root URL of the Kudu service is https://mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/
- To view Kudu service dashboard
  Azure Portal =>  your Web App =>  Select `Advanced Tools` => `Go` => `Debug Console` -> `CMD`:

[image]

- You can get to your application home directory by clicking the `site` folder =>`wwwroot` folder
- To remove a files/folder  click the `minus` icon

[image]

- ***Using [FileMage](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/filemagellc.filemage-gateway-vm-win?gclid=CjwKCAjw682TBhATEiwA9crl39mcCbIboeovs56AZeHKxXHF7Vb4h3EMyurVirxm4yJ712NAWuxKBhoC80cQAvD_BwE) - [Folder Permissions](https://docs.filemage.io/permissions.html#assigning-permissions) also you can delete files and folders.***